# UWP Unit Test for exit and restart of App

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-universal

I would like to write some Unit Tests which simulate the following:

```
1.) User starts my app
2.) User quits my app (unexpectantly during some operation)
3.) User restarts my app
4.) Unit test then checks to see that my code recovered from this.
```

Having [setup UWP Unit tests using these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/walkthrough-creating-and-running-unit-tests-for-windows-store-apps?view=vs-2017), I can see that the Unit Test project creates a test UWP app like this in UnitTestApp.xaml.cs file:

```
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.UnitTestClient.CreateDefaultUI();

        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();

        Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.UnitTestClient.Run(e.Arguments);
```

Ideally, I would like to somehow kill/quit/abort this Window (or its Frame, or ??) within a single Unit Test, and then restart it and have this Unit test, and the subsequent Unit tests continue.

If this is not feasible, then I would just like to know how others create unit tests that handle an exit and restart of their application.

I would prefer an answer for Visual Studio 2015, but instructions for Visual Studio 2017 would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to launch and control the app from test case just like [winui](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml) did,
UAPApp.Launch would help you launch the application.
I didn't see public doc about UAPApp.Launch, The signature can be found in [Microsoft.Windows.Apps.Test.chm](https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft.Windows.Apps.Test/blob/master/docs/Microsoft.Windows.Apps.Test.chm)

For example, for the [navigationview](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/master/dev/NavigationView/NavigationView_InteractionTests/NavigationViewTests.cs) tests, TestEnvironment did the magic:

```
 public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
    {
        TestEnvironment.Initialize(testContext);
    }
```

If you dive deep in [TestEnviroment](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/9e92494ddd71567fe0068fd2b0923b5d59f743c0/test/MUXControls.Test/Infra/TestEnvironment.cs), `CreateApplication` functions would new Application, and finally in Application.cs, testapp is launched by:

```
return UAPApp.Launch(_appName, topLevelWindowCondition);
```